# Why is the correct ID not being inserting into this table?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want the following code to insert the car's ID in the `customer_payment` table, but it only selects `477` as the ID. I don't know why. As it can be seen in image bellow only `product_id = 477` is inserted, not any other value. If I select 500 it still inserts 477.

[image]

```
include 'admin/db.php';

if(isset($_GET['payment_here'])){

    //select product id from cart
    $select_cart = "select * from cart";
    $runcart = mysqli_query($conn, $select_cart);
    $cartwhile=mysqli_fetch_assoc($runcart);

    $carssid = $cartwhile['P_ID'];
    $cusid = $cartwhile['C_ID'];

    //select id from cars
    $scars = "select * from cars where id=$carssid";
    $scarsrun = mysqli_query($conn, $scars);
    $showcars = mysqli_fetch_assoc($scarsrun);
    $carsdealer = $showcars['dealer'];


    //select customer id from customer  table
    //$selectcust = "select * from customer_register where id=$cusid";
    //insert data into customer payment table
    echo $insertpay = "insert into customer_payment 
    (Product_id, customer_id, dealer) 
    values ( $carssid," . $_SESSION['customer_id'] . ", '$carsdealer')";
    $run_inserts = mysqli_query($conn, $insertpay);
    /*
    if($run_inserts){
        echo "<script>window.location.href = 'checkout.php'</script>";
    }
    */
}
?>
```

Why is the correct ID not being inserting into this table?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do here

```
$select_cart = "select * from cart";
$runcart = mysqli_query($conn, $select_cart);
$cartwhile=mysqli_fetch_assoc($runcart); // here
```

is fetching the first entry from the 'cart' table which is always **going to be same.**

You can try something like this.

```
$c_id = $_SESSION['customer_id'];
$select_cart = "select * from cart where C_ID=$c_id";
$runcart = mysqli_query($conn, $select_cart);
$cartwhile=mysqli_fetch_assoc($runcart);
```

This query will specifically fetch data for customer of current session.
The rest of the code you can use as is.

Comment: it does enter the customer id whoever have logged in as shown in image 3. that's  fine the problem is with product_id why is it only selecting 477 product id .

Comment: because the **very first entry** in the cart table must be having customer_id as 477.

Comment: You are **inserting** customer id from current session but you are **not fetching** the data according to the current customer_id.

Comment: the 477 is the product_id means car id

Comment: What you are trying is that you are fetching **all the data** from the table 'cart'. But what you need to do is to **fetch** the data related to the **current** logged in customer. So for that you need to change the sql from `select * from cart` to `select * from cart where C_ID=$c_id` where $c_id is taken from the $_SESSION['customer_id']; So all the data that you are fetching now is related to the customer id which is in the first entry of the 'cart' table i.e. 3. Thats why the product_id is coming same i.e 477